How to mock a low level function In Rust while unit testing?
I am new in Rust.
For example.
I have a project constructure like this:

main.rs
low_level.rs
service.rs
.

There is a function in service mod using a function in low_level mod.It means when i want to assert the function in service ,it depends on the result of the function in low_level.
As we all know, there is a unit test rule called "Write Once,Run Everywhere".If the function in low_level has a feature of network IO.I hope i can mock this function to make sure that it can run everywhere.
I found there is not a simple way to implement it.
The usual way in Rust is #[cfg(test)] and #[cfg(not(test))].
But it means I have to  define the mock function before compling.
#[cfg(not(test))]

use low_level:read_from_net;

#[cfg(test)]
fn read_from_net(...) -> ... {
}

pub fn some_service_feature() -> ... {
    let result = read_from_net();
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
   #[test]
   fn test_some_service_function(){
      // assert here
   }

}

But if I have lots of test cases, I hope in my each cases, the result of low_level function is unique. This way just can`t make it .
So what do rusters usually do in such situation?
How to mock std::something in Rust?.
This article has already offer a solution. But it is not perfect for me.

"As we all know, there is a unit test rule called "Write Once,Run Everywhere"." - I do not know this rule and from what I do know the phrase is mostly a Java-ism about the JVM so I'm not sure what "everywhere" means when you're applying the principle to unit tests. Do you really mean that your tests should work regardless of OS and platform architecture? A good principle but I'm not sure how it applies to your question. Maybe I'm just being pedantic.

"But if I have lots of test cases, I hope in my each cases, the result of low_level function is unique" - its not clear to me how "uniqueness" plays in to your tests. If you need the mocked function to yield different results depending on the tests (to account for different success / error results) then you likely do want to use dependency injection as answered below instead of #[cfg]s.

To mock network functions in Rust for unit tests, the best approach in your case is dependency injection:

Define a trait for your network function NetworkReader.
In your service module, accept a type that implements this trait.
In tests, create a mock implementation of the trait and inject it into the service function.

Example:

low_level.rs :

pub trait NetworkReader {
    fn read_from_net(&self) -> String;
}

pub struct RealNetworkReader;

impl NetworkReader for RealNetworkReader {
    fn read_from_net(&self) -> String {
        "real data".to_string()
    }
}


service.rs :

use crate::low_level::NetworkReader;

pub fn some_service_feature<R: NetworkReader>(reader: R) -> String {
    reader.read_from_net()
}


tests.rs :

use crate::service::some_service_feature;
use crate::low_level::NetworkReader;

struct MockNetworkReader {
    mock_response: String,
}

impl NetworkReader for MockNetworkReader {
    fn read_from_net(&self) -> String {
        self.mock_response.clone()
    }
}

#[test]
fn test_some_service_function() {
    let mock_reader = MockNetworkReader {
        mock_response: "mocked data".to_string(),
    };
    let result = some_service_feature(mock_reader);
    assert_eq!(result, "mocked data");
}

